# Could not create directory - wordpress plugin installation failure on mac

Tags: wordpress, macos, plugins, localhost, failed-installation

Good day folks
I tried to install wordpress plugins in Mac in localhost but i am getting this error:
Could not create directory. /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kew/wp-content/plugins/revslider/

Plugin install failed.
I changed the permissions of the installation folder to Read & Write but the error is not resolved.
Kindly assist me.

Regards

Comment: Read and write for folder corresponds to a number like 777, 650.... Have a look to the file and folder permissions reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 11):

You need to set permission on plugin folder/directory.
Via terminal write this

`sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content`

Comment: it can be dangers in the production. Be very careful

Comment: @KrishnaKarki, how can it be a danger, I"m just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the terminal:

1. sudo chmod 0775 /Library/WebServer/Documents
2. sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a username -t user _www
3. rahulmahato$ sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a rahulmahato -t user _www

Note: Replace username with yours :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go through the parent folder of "wp-content" folder.
2. Right click on folder and chhose "New Terminal at folder"
3. Via terminal write this ***sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content***
4. Enter and done.